# JSON response problems for authentication form using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new using Angularjs and I am having an issue parsing a `JSON` response. I am doing **client side authentication** , I know it's bad practice, but I want it to learn.

HTML Code :

```
<form ng-submit="loginform(logcred)" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid center" name="logform"><br/><br>
<tr ng-repeat="logcred in serverinfo"></tr>
<div>
  <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="uname" id="emailinput" placeholder="you@example.com" ng-model="logcred.username" >
</div>

<div>
  <label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" id="pwdinput" placeholder="*******" ng-model="logcred.password">
</div>

<div>
    <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
</div>
<br/>   
</form>
```

AngularJS :

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('credientials', function($scope, $http) {
/* server side response*/
      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/loginfo')
      .then(
       function successCallback(response){
       $scope.serverinfo = response.data;
      });       

/* client-side response*/
    $scope.loginform = function(userData){
      $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/loginfo',
        method: 'POST',
        data: userData
     })
      .then(
      function successCallback(response){
        if (userData.username === response.data.username && userData.password === response.data.password) { 
        $scope.signinfo = response.data;
      }else{
      console.log("Error: " + response)
    }
    });
    }
    });
```

Response data:

```
Object { username: "admin@evol.io", password: "admin" }
```

In the Above code I am execute a `POST` request on the server, specifying username and password inserted by the user. The server should check the `if` condition from server, to check if there are any rows with that name and password. If yes return true, if false return false. then the client should parse this response. I already fetch the response from server , but **I don't know why the `if` condition is failing to give the response**.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what will be the response of your loginfo server method ? loginfo is a post method or get method ? I think you have used get and post request to the same method from your code

Comment: users : username and password. `loginfo` is a post method

Comment: first i am fetching the response from server using `get`. After that i am trying to parse with `post`, where client will enter there credentials

Comment: what you get in `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: put a console.log in your success method and see response.data output, and tell us what is response.data returns ?

Comment: i am getting the `post` response data , where the user will enter there name and password @jitender

Comment: userData will contain the data which will be entered by user @ArunprasanthKV

Comment: can you please include the response.data object value in the question.

Comment: actually i have made a mistake in `if` condition. when input that data should will be posted and that data should be verified in server side. But i donot know how to do that

Comment: I think you have to use a database for that. It seems you are not using database. If i understand you correctly then you are sending user credentials to server and trying to validate it in the next call, it wont work out . You may have to use database, files or at least session storage

Comment: let me see the server side method loginfo?

Comment: Thanks Arun. Your understanding is correct . I will correct my mistake.Do u have any small working code based on session storage @ArunprasanthKV

Comment: for server side i am using get request and storing it in **serverinfo**

Comment: include your server side code in the question

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV. I have uploaded the code in my question. Please take a look over it

Comment: I couldn't  see any server side code in your question

Comment: i have mentioned **server-side response** in the comment. That's what i am fetching from server